# Build org agenda based on org-roam tags

Tags: org-agenda, org-roam

I need to populate my org-agenda with items collected from org-roam nodes based on their TAGS (i.e. nodes tagged as "project" or "payments"), but I definitely lack the necessary elisp skills. So I'm asking for your kind help.
I asked ChatGPT 3 to write me a possible solution (please do not blame me more than I already did) but being knowledgeable until Sep-2021 it knows nothing about org-roam V2. Here's what it suggests

```
(defun my/org-roam-filter-by-tags (tag-names)
  (lambda (node)
    (let ((node-tags (org-roam-node-tags node)))
      (cl-some (lambda (tag) (member tag node-tags)) tag-names))))

(setq my-tags '("tag1" "tag2"))
(setq filtered-nodes (seq-filter (my/org-roam-filter-by-tags my-tags) org-roam-db))
```

Problem is that `org-roam-db` doesn't exist anymore so `setq` returns `void`. Can anybody help be adapting this code (if possible) to org-roam v2?

Comment: This would still need to be connected to the agenda, probably through `org-agenda-custom-commands` but there is no mention of that in the code snippet.

Comment: Is this https://systemcrafters.net/build-a-second-brain-in-emacs/5-org-roam-hacks/#build-your-org-agenda-from-org-roam-notes what you mean?

Comment: It definitely needs to be connected to the agenda. In fact the idea is to compile a list of files to populate `org-agenda-files`

Comment: Yes! The very first idea is absolutely taken from systemcrafters' function to collect org-roam nodes by a tag. In his case he uses only one tag ("Project"). I'd like to extend the functionality to several tags.